# Saving fields of new extension in Magento

Tags: magento

I am new in Magento and creating a custom extension. My module is not in Configuration tab under System. I have two fields in module and wanted to save these fields in db.

Kindly help me with this. Should I create a new table for this or simply save it to config table of Magento?

Comment: what purpose do they do?

Comment: if your module is independent one, then you need to create a custom table and need to save your data into that table. But if your module is a part of already existing modules in magento, then depend upon that module, you need to decide whether a custom table is required or not